# PXE server with NFS

Tags: nfs, pxe

Ubuntu 21.10

I setup a functional PXE server but lately I received an error. I supposed the NFS export does not work. The permissions are 777. Can anybody have a solution to that?

I followed [this](https://linuxhint.com/pxe_boot_ubuntu_server/)

/etc/exports:

```
/netboot/nfs *(rw,sync,no_wdelay,insecure_locks,no_root_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

this is Ubuntu 16.04 image.
[image]

I resolved the issue so now, the live media boots over PXE OK.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the content of `/etc/exports`.

Comment: I did include /etc/exports in OP